# Ajax loaded partial view not rendering

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am making an ajax call to retrieve a partial view and put inside a div.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPartial", "ControllerName")',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#myDiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

However, `#myDiv` doesn't get any html in it when I have `$('#myDiv').html(data);` but when I try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPartial", "ControllerName")',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#myDiv').html("<div>Whatever</div>");
    }
});
```

The div gets filled with `<div>Whatever</div>`, as expected. So here are the contents of the `data` variable:

```
<tr>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px" name="credit-card" value="fjxtnw" checked />
    <strong>555555******4444</strong> (MasterCard)
    <label style="color: #808080; font-size: small">(default)</label>
    <span id="fjxtnw" class="delete_pm"><label style="color: darkred; font-size: small; margin-left: 5px">delete</label></span>
</tr>
<br />
<br />
<tr>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px" name="credit-card" value="9rmqsw" />
    <strong>411111******1111</strong> (Visa)
    <span id="9rmqsw" class="delete_pm"><label style="color: darkred; font-size: small; margin-left: 5px">delete</label></span>
</tr>
<br />
<br />
```

But nothing gets rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see you using the "data" in the success call back ... at least you should have something like ..  $('#myDiv').html("<div>Whatever : "+data+"</div>");

Comment: @Sam.C, I do use it, read carefully, my first code snippet shows it being used

Comment: @Sam.C, yep, the returned data is described in the last code snippet, that's what come in the `data` variable

Comment: The problem is you are trying to put "tr" element in a "div" ... try adding it in a body of a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial view you are returning is not well formatted table HTML so it should be something like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
<td>
        <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px" name="credit-card" value="fjxtnw" checked />
        <strong>555555******4444</strong> (MasterCard)
        <label style="color: #808080; font-size: small">(default)</label>
        <span id="fjxtnw" class="delete_pm"><label style="color: darkred; font-size: small; margin-left: 5px">delete</label></span>
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
<td>
            <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px" name="credit-card" value="9rmqsw" />
            <strong>411111******1111</strong> (Visa)
            <span id="9rmqsw" class="delete_pm"><label style="color: darkred; font-size: small; margin-left: 5px">delete</label></span>
</td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

then your jquery can be just

```
$('#myDiv').html(data);
```

or if you already have a table HTML where you just want to plug in the rows you could do ... remove the "table" tag and update the jquery as :

```
$("#myTable").append(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. I had already found the solution, I guessed it had something to do with the structure. I didn't need the `table` tag, just the `td` tags after the `tr` ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#myDiv').html(data.d);`

Or test a `console.log(data)` to see the object is coming..

Comment: The object is coming and it contains what I posted in the question - see my last code snippet

Comment: Ok. And it is coming as a text directly or in a js object?

Comment: As plain text Pedrito

Comment: So, try pass the value to another variable like `success: function (data) {
        var d = data;
        $('#myDiv').html(d);
    }` (but i have not idea what i'm doing)

Comment: :) [You are right](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/japbcvpavbzau9dbuaxf.jpg)! Thanks for the effort though!